# HP Smart Array P400 controller reports physical drives incorrectly

Tags: raid, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I've been researching on this the majority of the day, when I had time to blow.

But now it's just becoming a headache, when I ask the HP P400 for detailed Information on the drives connected to the backplane it gives them all the same drive number, and model.
I believe it is related to the problem in http://www.motherboardpoint.com/hp-p400-raid-controller-reporting-p-disks-incorrectly-t232845.html but as far as I know this is the official HP Backplane, It's a HP SE 1102 server, all original.

```
  Logical Drive: 1
     Size: 1.8 TB
     Fault Tolerance: RAID 1+0
     Heads: 255
     Sectors Per Track: 63
     Cylinders: 65535
     Strip Size: 64 KB
     Full Stripe Size: 128 KB
     Status: OK
     Caching:  Enabled
     Unique Identifier: 600508B1001046395656364131340005
     Disk Name: /dev/cciss/c0d0
     Mount Points: /boot 200 MB, / 19.5 GB, /vz 1.8 TB
     OS Status: LOCKED
     Logical Drive Label: A03F08CAP61620F9VV6A144897
     Mirror Group 0:
        physicaldrive 0:0 (box 0:bay 0, SATA, 1 TB, OK)
        physicaldrive 0:0 (box 0:bay 0, SATA, 1 TB, OK)
     Mirror Group 1:
        physicaldrive 0:0 (box 0:bay 0, SATA, 1 TB, OK)
        physicaldrive 0:0 (box 0:bay 0, SATA, 1 TB, OK)
     Drive Type: Data
```

Array: A
      Interface Type: SATA
      Unused Space: 0  MB
      Status: OK
      Array Type: Data

```
  physicaldrive 0:0
     Box: 0
     Bay: 0
     Status: OK
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SATA
     Size: 1 TB
     Firmware Revision: 1AJ10001
     Serial Number: 
     Model: ATA     SAMSUNG HE103SJ
     SATA NCQ Capable: True
     SATA NCQ Enabled: True
     PHY Count: 1
     PHY Transfer Rate: 1.5Gbps

  physicaldrive 0:0
     Box: 0
     Bay: 0
     Status: OK
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SATA
     Size: 1 TB
     Firmware Revision: 1AJ10001
     Serial Number: 
     Model: ATA     SAMSUNG HE103SJ
     SATA NCQ Capable: True
     SATA NCQ Enabled: True
     PHY Count: 1
     PHY Transfer Rate: 1.5Gbps

  physicaldrive 0:0
     Box: 0
     Bay: 0
     Status: OK
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SATA
     Size: 1 TB
     Firmware Revision: 1AJ10001
     Serial Number: 
     Model: ATA     SAMSUNG HE103SJ
     SATA NCQ Capable: True
     SATA NCQ Enabled: True
     PHY Count: 1
     PHY Transfer Rate: 1.5Gbps

  physicaldrive 0:0
     Box: 0
     Bay: 0
     Status: OK
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SATA
     Size: 1 TB
     Firmware Revision: 1AJ10001
     Serial Number: 
     Model: ATA     SAMSUNG HE103SJ
     SATA NCQ Capable: True
     SATA NCQ Enabled: True
     PHY Count: 1
     PHY Transfer Rate: 1.5Gbps
```

HE103SJ does not represent every drive in the server, there is seagate constellations, and a WD RE4. (Weird combination, huh, don't ask why :P).

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here, and what solutions do I have if a drive fails, I cannot just delete 0:0 since I assume it'll delete all drives with the id "0:0".

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're using cheap SATA disks on an HP Smart Array P400 controller. Which firmware version is the controller running? What version of `hpacucli` are you running?

Please also include the full output of `hpacucli ctrl all show config detail`.

This can happen in some cases. It's not a big deal:

```
=> ctrl all show config

Smart Array P410i in Slot 0 (Embedded)    (sn: 50014380054E9DA0)

   array A (SAS, Unused Space: 1188170  MB)


      logicaldrive 1 (72.0 GB, RAID 1+0, OK)
      logicaldrive 2 (400.0 GB, RAID 1+0, OK)
      logicaldrive 3 (517.6 GB, RAID 5, OK)

      physicaldrive 0:0 (box 0:bay 0, SAS, 750 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 0:0 (box 0:bay 0, SAS, 750 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 0:0 (box 0:bay 0, SAS, 750 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 0:0 (box 0:bay 0, SAS, 750 GB, OK)
```

Yet...

```
     Mirror Group 0:
        physicaldrive 0:0 (box 0:bay 0, SAS, 750 GB, OK)
        physicaldrive 0:0 (box 0:bay 0, SAS, 1 TB, OK)
     Mirror Group 1:
        physicaldrive 0:0 (box 0:bay 0, SAS, 750 GB, OK)
        physicaldrive 0:0 (box 0:bay 0, SAS, 1 TB, OK)
```

However, I've had drives in this array fail and all has been well. The drive indicator and email alert worked as usual. Anyway, you should not need to take any action in `hpacucli` if a drive fails. And you definitely shouldn't use the `delete` command :)

---

Edit:

I don't know what OS you're using - it looks like a Linux of some sort... but the right Smart Array P400 firmware can either be be applied using the [bootable HP Firmware Update DVD](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?swItem=MTX-9ed665a89aba447d925937f38b&lang=en&cc=us&mode=3&) or directly from the operating system using the [Linux firmware available here](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=1121516&prodNameId=3288134&swEnvOID=4006&swLang=8&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-bc1046a3541a46389b7fa2d755&mode=3).

Comment: hpacucli ctrl all show config detail was too long to show fully, but it seems the firmware is out of date, Not sure where I find the right firmware. FIRMWARE UPGRADE REQUIRED: A firmware update is recommended for this controller
                           to prevent rare potential data write errors on a
                           RAID 1 or RAID 1+0 volume in a scenario of
                           concurrent background surface analysis and I/O write
                           operations.  Please refer to Customer Advisory
                           c01587778 which can be found at hp.com.

Comment: See my update above.

Comment: @user156235 As far as I can see, the firmware upgrade DVDs have been discontinued and superseded by the [HP Service Pack for Proliant DVDs](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/management/spp/index.html) which seem to include the firmware update utility along with the latest firmware for the controller. The latest current release is 2012.10 (October 2012).

Comment: @syneticon-dj While the HP Service Pack for ProLiant is available, it's still in a transitional period and offers no firmware advantage for old systems with Smart Array P400 controllers (G5 systems) versus the last release of the Firmware DVD I linked above. Also, a nearly 3GB download for a small array controller firmware is unnecessary.The Firmware DVD is apt in this case.

Comment: @ewwhite Umm. What I see [here](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?cc=de&prodNameId=1157689&prodTypeId=329290&prodSeriesId=1157687&swLang=13&taskId=135&swEnvOID=54) is a `* RECOMMENDED * Supplemental Update / Online ROM Flash Component for Linux - Smart Array P400 and P400i` dated Sep, 4th 2012 (unlikely to be found on the Firmware Upgrade DVD dating from June 2012).

Comment: @ewwhite Also, HP states ["*Smart Update Firmware DVD Version: 10.10 (4 Jun 2012) is the final version of the Smart Update Firmware DVD. The HP Service Pack for ProLiant (SPP) will replace the Smart Update Firmware DVD later this year. During this transition period, both products are released concurrently* ***for this final time.***"](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=120&prodSeriesId=3716246&prodTypeId=18964&objectID=c03417344) (emphasis is mine), so if you need the *latest* firmware, you should download the SPP DVD instead, right?

Comment: @syneticon-dj The P400 controller is currently at version 7.24 of firmware from Sept. 2012. Prior to that, the version was 7.22, dated Oct. 2010. The difference between the two versions is inconsequential for the purposes of the OP's problem (see [changelog](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=1121516&swItem=MTX-bc1046a3541a46389b7fa2d755&prodNameId=3288134&swEnvOID=4006&swLang=8&taskId=135&mode=5)). I made the specific recommendation for a reason. This would be different if we were discussing a G6 or newer server

Comment: @syneticon-dj Sorry for the rant. I'm just not happy with how HP packaged the new SPP DVD. It's far too large and it discourages people from running all of the updates.

Comment: We would have to pay remote hands for the USB way, I'm not sure on this command. I can see two seperate download links part1 and part2.                                                            
    Login as root. (You must be root in order to apply the ROM update.)
    Place the Smart Component in a temporary directory.
    From the same directory, execute the Smart Component. For example: ./CPXXXXXX.scexe
    Follow the directions given by the Smart Component.
    Reboot your system if you would like the update to take effect immediately.
.

Comment: Thanks all! Firmware installed, just got to reboot! Hopefully this will help someone else who also has this problem. :)

Comment: @ewwhite lately, I had the mixed blessing of a chance to use the SPP DVD for firmware updates. *I needed a* ***mouse*** *to navigate through*. So probably both, your unhappiness and the rant are justified.